# When the action of reductive group on algebraic variety is not equidimensional?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, algebraic-groups, geometric-invariant-theory

I saw the question [When is an almost geometric quotient flat?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/247257/when-is-an-almost-geometric-quotient-flat) which said

> "The quotient $\pi$ is flat if and only if $\pi$ is equidimensional and $X$ is smooth".

I am curious is there an example that $\pi$ is not equidimensional. Also where can I see the original reference for the statement?

Comment: As explained in the question you quote, the case where $\pi$ *is* equidimensional is actually quite rare. The paper *Representations with a free module of covariants* by V. Popov (Functional Anal. Appi. 10 (1976), 242-243) gives a complete list of these cases for irreducible representations of an almost simple, simply connected group; just take any representation which is not in that list.

Comment: @abx Thank you for the detail, because I am a beginner on this subject, I am not familiar with notations and concepts of the paper. Could you show me an easy examples? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Consider the action of the multiplicative group $\mathbb{G}_m =\text{Spec}\ k[t,t^{-1}]$ on $\mathbb{A}^3=\text{Spec}\ k[x,y,z]$ by $t\cdot(x,y,z) = (tx,ty,t^{-1}z)$.  The categorical quotient is given by the morphism of affine $k$-schemes associated to the inclusion of rings $k[u,v]\hookrightarrow k[x,y,z]$ by $u\mapsto xz$ and $v\mapsto yz$.  This morphism is flat of relative dimension $1$ over the complement of the origin in $\text{Spec}\ k[u,v]$, but the fiber over the origin has a component of dimension $2$.